# fileread error .FileInputStream.readBytes(Native Method)

Tags: mysql, database, file-io, insert

im trying to get the data from text file and insert in to mysql database..some of rows are successfuly inserted but when runing the program it shows this error message..

```
java.io.IOException: Read error
at java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:199)
at java.io.DataInputStream.read(DataInputStream.java:132)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:264)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:306)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:158)
at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:167)
at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:136)
at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:299)
at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:362)
at InsertDB.inserdata(InsertDB.java:53)
at InsertDB.main(InsertDB.java:96)
```

this is my program

```
 public class InsertDB {
    Connection conn ;
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
    String dbName = "dna";
    String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    String userName = "root"; 
    String password = "123";

    public void inserdata()
    {


      String[] RowItems = new String[11];
      int[] intRowItems=new int[10];
    try{
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url+dbName,userName,password);
     Statement st = conn.createStatement();
     // Open the file that is the first 
    // command line parameter
     FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("result.txt");
    // Get the object of DataInputStream
    DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
    String strLine;
    StringTokenizer stringTokenizer ;





    while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
    stringTokenizer=new StringTokenizer(strLine);
   int j=0;
   while(stringTokenizer.hasMoreTokens()){
    RowItems[j]=stringTokenizer.nextToken();
    j++;
    }
   int c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,c7,c8,c9,c10,c11;

      c2=Integer.valueOf(RowItems[1]).intValue();
       c3=Integer.valueOf(RowItems[2]).intValue();
        c4=Integer.valueOf(RowItems[3]).intValue();
         c5=Integer.valueOf(RowItems[4]).intValue();
          c6=Integer.valueOf(RowItems[5]).intValue();
           c7=Integer.valueOf(RowItems[6]).intValue();
            c8=Integer.valueOf(RowItems[7]).intValue();
             c9=Integer.valueOf(RowItems[8]).intValue();
              c10=Integer.valueOf(RowItems[9]).intValue();
               c11=Integer.valueOf(RowItems[10]).intValue();

     String temp=RowItems[0];
    String insert="INSERT into protein_predicted                 VALUES('"+temp+"','"+c2+"','"+c3+"','"+c4+"','"+c5+"','"+c6+"','"+c7+"','"+c8+"','"+c9+"','      "+c10+"','"+c11+"')";
    st.executeUpdate(insert);

    in.close();
    }
    System.out.println("Insertted successfully");
     }
       catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
       }
       catch (Exception e){//Catch exception if any
        //System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
      e.printStackTrace();
      //Close the input stream



    }
    }
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        InsertDB a=new InsertDB();
        a.inserdata();


    }
```

my text file contains multiple columns and multiple rows like this

1BG8A   76  33  0   18  1   0   1   5   2   16

please help me to slove this..thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are closing your `DataInputStream` inside of the `while` loop that is reading it. I would remove that `in.close()` line and outside of the while loop close your `BufferedReader` after you are done reading everything using `br.close();`

If you are using Java 6 or below you would, ideally, declare the `BufferedReader` variable outside of the `try`...`catch` and add a `finally` clause to close the reader in case a read error happens. In Java 7 there's an [AutoCloseable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html) interface that helps handle this automatically.